# Pnp JS getting data from list

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, pnpjs

I am trying out pnpjs USING SharePoint framework and adding new item to my list.

But when I try to gulp serve and run it inside my SharePoint Online

```
const iar: IItemAddResult = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(ListName).items.add({
    Title: "Title",
})
```

When I try to run its trying to get the information in my list but it has "_layouts/15" on it.

```
[O365Url]/sites/LimitTester/_layouts/15/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('CrudTestOnly')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```

Comment: Are you running this on SharePoint workbench (_layouts/workbench.aspx)?

Comment: Yes I am [O365Url]/sites/LimitTester/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx#

Comment: @Hawk, Is there any update ? Have you tried the solution in the answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to set up correct spfxContent like this in WebPartName.ts:

```
public onInit(): Promise<void> {

  return super.onInit().then(_ => {

    // other init code may be present

    sp.setup({
      spfxContext: this.context
    });
  });
}
```

[image]